# Bot resetting things in the code after a few minutes (Discord.JS)

Tags: javascript, bots, discord.js

I'm currently working on a mini game for my bot, the code works fine but there is an issue. I'll explain what is happening under the code:

```
var coins = 0;
const PREFIX = '!'

bot.on("message", msg => {
  let args = msg.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");
  switch (args[0]) {
    case "coins":
      const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle(`Your coins`)
        .setDescription(`${msg.author} has ${coins} coins`);
      msg.channel.send(embed)
      break;
    case "dig":
      const randomCoin = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)
      coins += randomCoin
      msg.channel.send(`You went digging for coins and found ${randomCoin} coins.\nYou now have ${coins} coins.`)
  }
});
```

Once again, this code runs fine, but the problem is that after waiting for approximately 5 minutes or so, everything resets. This means that the coins go back to 0. Everything I've tried just wouldn't work. I tried using a `setTimeout()`, but that wouldn't work (wasn't too sure how to implement it in this case, but I did try using it where I thought it should go, but no success).

How can I make it so that nothing resets? I would really appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: You need to store the `coins` value in a database or a json file

Comment: @Syntle  Will maps work? Sorry, not the best at this.

Comment: No, you need a persistent form of storage

Comment: @Syntle Can you give an example? Thanks!

Comment: I suggest you check out the official discord.js guide on how to create a currency system. It'll help point you in the right direction: https://discordjs.guide/sequelize/currency.html#file-overview

Comment: Alright got it. Thank you so much!